# Laravel websocket in subdirectory

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-echo, phpwebsocket, pusher-js

please can you help me.

My scheme of files is:

```
var/www/turnerosac --> files base projects
/var/www/html/turnerosac --> files public
```

When executing the command:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/turnerosac/artisan websocket:serve
```

Throw the following message in the console

```
Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...
New connection opened for app key e992c96bf63f43766490.
Connection id 154192426.353203179 sending message {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{"socket_id":"154192426.353203179","activity_timeout":30}"}
```

My bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'e992c96bf63f43766490',
    cluster: 'us2',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001
    // disableStats: true,
});
```

In browser

Comment: So... what's the problem exactly?

Comment: When I run my program with 
php artisan websocket:serve 
with the structure of 
/var/www/ turnerosac/public run, 
but when the folder structure is separated it stops working